# Usage of "let" with an inanimate subject

Tags: verbs, subjects, animacy

Can anyone help me and explain if the usage of "let" together with "these things" is grammatically correct in the following passage?

> We have created many useful things such as airplanes, trains,
>   computers, medicines, as well as institutions such as schools,
>   universities, hospitals and banks. Without them the modern world would
>   not exist. **These things** **let** us travel far and wide, gather
>   information quickly, educate ourselves, and treat diseases.

In my grammar textbook, they say you cannot use "let" with an inanimate subject. Personally, I didn't find the sentence strange when reading, but it should be wrong and corrected according to the grammar book. This sentence sounds OK to me; is that because the subject is a pronoun, "these things," although "thing" is still inanimate.

And if that is the case, how about this sentence below?

> *Airplanes and trains let us travel far and wide.*

This does not sound too awkward either, but to be grammatically correct, does the sentence below look better?

> *Airplanes and trains enable/allow us to travel far and wide.*

Please anyone help me find out if you cannot really use "let" with an inanimate subject. Thanks!!

Comment: Time to get a different grammar textbook. Those examples you quoted are absolutely fine and idiomatic.

Comment: Let it be. No problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason why *let* should not be used with an inanimate subject — just as *enable* or *allow* can be. *Let* is a synonym, after all; if an inanimate object can **allow** something, then it can **let** it happen, too.

There **may** be an issue where *let* is used in its archaic/obsolescent sense of *hinder* (the tennis call of "Let!" is used when the ball is hindered in its passage by hitting the net; there is also the fixed phrase "let and hindrance"). In **this** case, *let* is very rarely used in an active form; if it's only used in the passive voice, it doesn't have a subject at all, inanimate or not.

Comment: Thanks! I got the same explanation as yours from several different people. Wonder why they make up such rules that nobody uses in the real world.